# How can I let WPF Window stay in front of certain window but not topmost?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

here is the situation

my WPF Main window is always visible and several small windows should be floating **on** the Main Window.
So these small windows are children of Main Window and their z-index should be always one greater than Main Window even if the focus is on the main window rather than children but smaller z-index than other applications (e.g. file browser or chrome etc.)

I've tried Window's **TopMost** property but it makes really top most than everything else even more than application's MessageBox.

any good idea for making these children windows are just floating in front of only parent window?

thanks in advance

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for the [`Window.Owner`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.owner?view=net-5.0#remarks) property. Setting your main `Window` as the `Owner` of the child `Windows` will, among other things, prevent the main `Window` from displaying over the child `Windows` while allowing other applications to display behind, in-between, or over your application.

Comment: Thanks! I found a proper answer. I think i just missed proper keyword to search for answers in stackoverflow. when I searched with "owner" keyword there are some similar questions and it resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should automatically open above the owner window. Or set the child to be topmost